# Changing colnames of the nth element of a list of data.frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, names

I have a list of data frames names

I used objects() to get them.

```
my_list <- objects()

my_list

[1]"df1"
[2]"df2"
[3]"df3"
[4]"df4"
...
```

Each data frame has 7 columns

I have 3 different character vectors `v1,v2,v3`(length 4) that I want to use to name the first 4 columns of the data frames. I basically want to reuse those vectors in that order until all the columns in my data.frame list are named.

IMPORTANT: I want to use the 3 vectors to name all the data frames. `v1` to name `df1`, `v2` to name `df2`, `v3` to name `df3`, `v1` AGAIN to name `df4`, etc...

```
df1

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

v1 <- c(a,b,c,d)    


magic(my_list)

df1

   a  b  c  d X5 X6 X7
 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setnames from the data.table package will work.

```
setnames(df,old = c(1:4), new = v1[1:4])
```

edit: If you want to do that for your entire list, you can use lapply.

```
lapply(l, function(x) setnames(x,old = c(1:4), new = v1[1:4]))
```

edit2:Recycling the 3 vectors, and keeping it a bit easy to read -

```
 for (i in 1:length(l))
          {
  if (i%%3 == 1) {
    setnames(l[[i]],old = c(1:4), new = v1[1:4])
  }
  else if (i%%3 == 2) {
    setnames(l[[i]],old = c(1:4), new = v2[1:4])
  }
  if (i%%3 == 0) {
    setnames(l[[i]],old = c(1:4), new = v3[1:4])
  }
}
```

Comment: correct, just the first 4

Comment: I'm not very familiar with data.table yet, and I'm relatively new to R. How could I recycle the 3 vectors through my list of data frames?

Comment: My answer should work if you havent seen it yet @jesusgarciab